# Getting shopify storeURL from shopify app

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

I have created a public app and embeded it into Shopify store. I dont have access to anything outside my code.

`Store url when using app: "https://namestore.myshopify.com/admin/apps/name-app"`

I have use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it return my app url instead of User url. I cant use javascript because I check url to redirect user to my billing page or if not change the current page into my billing page.

What I want: A way to get the parenturl from the code which is inside an Iframe

Answer (score 0):

This is passed as a parameter to your app proxy.

From [the documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/application-proxies#handling-proxy-requests):

```
GET /proxy/extra/path/components?extra=1&extra=2&shop=shop-name.myshopify.com&path_prefix=%2Fapps%2Fawesome_reviews&timestamp=1317327555&signature=a9718877bea71c2484f91608a7eaea1532bdf71f5c56825065fa4ccabe549ef3 HTTP/1.1
  Host: proxy-domain.com
  X-Forwarded-For: 123.123.123.123
```

Comment: hi Gavin, could you tell more how it work because idk what app proxy is?

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread your question. When you said you have embedded your app typically that means you are using an App proxy. Please see the link I provided to learn more about Shopify App proxies.